# Unable to boot kali linux in virtual box

Tags: windows, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am having a problem booting Kali Linux 32 bit on my laptop.
First I created the new virtual machine with following config:

1. Type: linux
2. Version: linux 2.6/3.x/4.x (32 bit)
3. Ram: 1024 mb
4. virtual hard disk
5. hard disk space - 25 gb
6. hard disk file type- VDI
7. dynamically allocated

After that I ran it and chose my iso file and started it. Then I hit LIVE (686-pae), but it gave me this error:

```
- unable to boot - please use kernel appropriate for your cpu.
```

I did some research and found a solution which fixed this error by checking "enable PAE/NX" in the processor settings.

[image]

I started it again, but it stopped on the following screen:

[image: Loading, please wait...]

What should I do next?

Comment: Personally I had trouble with installing Kali on virtualbox as well. It's not quite a solution to your problem, but you could download a virtualbox image with Kali already installed over here: https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/ which works just fine!

Comment: Did you enable CPU virtualization in BIOS?

Comment: As Kali Linux is derived from Debian, Try selecting Debian (32-bit) on General > Basic > Version, instead of Version- linux 2.6/3.x/4.x (32 bit)

Comment: Try to increase the VM memory before booting from the iso. If I remember, Kali, needs quite a bit of memory to run. Wouldn't hurt to increase to numbers of CPU cores as part of you debugging.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i -o vmx`

Comment: Also, what OS are you running on your laptop? Linux? Windows? OSX? I'm talking about the one that boots normally.

Comment: @johnLeuenhagen My laptop have windows 8.1

Comment: @ErikvandeVen i have downloaded it now what i have to do

Comment: Please download the utility found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592#filelist), run it, and post its output.

Comment: @johnLeuenhagen this utility does not run on windows 8.1

Comment: @Zicsus Long story short, I suspect that you either do not have virtualization enabled on your computer, or it does not support it. Check in your BIOS to see if there is an option that has something to do with virtualization, ensure that it is enabled, and tell me what options you found afterwards. On most computers you need to hold F2 when the computer is booting up. You will likely be able to see which button you need to press on the screen as the computer boots. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate pae first. I don't know how the buttons are called in english because Im using the german version but I guess its processor-> activate pae

Comment: The question says that the OP has already done System → Processor → ✓ Enable PAE/NX.